# Iterate over json array and combine values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Here is my sample JSON array:

```
{
  "repository": "sample-repo-url",
  "stringsFound": {
    "0": ["test-stringsFound0"],
    "1": ["test-stringsFound1"],
    "2": ["test-stringsFound2"]
  },
  "reason": {
    "0": ["test-reason0"],
    "1": ["test-reason1"],
    "2": ["test-reason2"]
  },
  "path": {
    "0": ["test-path0"],
    "1": ["test-path1"],
    "2": ["test-path2"]
  }
}
```

I need to be able to combine `reason`, `path`, and `stringsFound` by their values and print them out.

For example:

```
test-stringsFound0 -- test-reason0 -- test-path0
test-stringsFound0 -- test-reason1 -- test-path1
```

and so on.

How do I go about doing this iteratively?

Comment: Please provide your code. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: What's the problem? JSON parsing or working with the parsed data?

Comment: print(json_array["path"]["0"]

this prints test-path0

print(json_array["reason"]["0"]

this prints test-reason0

Comment: That json looks like a single dict, except it ends with a comma, so that implies there are more entries you haven't shown us.  Please show us the actual full json.

Comment: How do I iterate over the values. If I do, for i in range(len(json_array["path"].items()):
   
print(json_array["path"][i]

it gives me an error

Comment: Apologies for the stupid formatting

Comment: The other entries are similar objects in the same format with different values. The actual output is too large to display here

Comment: Iterate over `json_array['path'].keys()`.  That will give you a list of `["0", "1", "2", ...]`, which you can then use to index into the `stringsFound`, `reason`, and `path` sub-dicts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this is helpful. How do I iterate/index over the subdicts?

for i in json_array['path'].keys():

    print json_array['path'][i]

gives an error. I'm sure this is a minor syntax modification but I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
for each in zip(d['stringsFound'].values(), d['reason'].values(), d['path'].values()):
    print(f'{each[0][0]} -- {each[1][0]} -- {each[2][0]}')
```